# Mocking internal calls of a function being tested using googlemock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I am new to Google Mock and based on my understanding of the documentation and online resources, I could not identify a solution to my problem:

I have the following classes:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A() { }
        int fun1()
        {
            //Some code
            B b;
            x = b.fun2();
            //Some other code
        }
};
class B
{
    public:
        B() { }
        int fun2()
        {
            //Some code
            y = C::fun3();
            //Some code
        }
};
class C
{
    public:
        static int fun3()
        {
            //Read a file and provide success if a certain pattern is found
        }
};
```

Now I am trying to write a Google test for A::fun1(). But because of the structure of the code (all the calls are through objects and I do not have a base class using which I can initialize a mock etc., I am not able to mock this successfully.

Can someone help me understand if this is mockable with Google Mock in its current form? Please note that I am not allowed to change the original source code.

Comment: I'm just assuming you want to mock `class B`, can you confirm this and precise your question about it?

Comment: Actually, I want to mock class B or class C. The biggest problem I have in this case is the fact that C::fun3() is accessing an external file.

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this as long the class under test can be configured using static interfaces (i.e. template parameters). See here for more information: [Mocking Nonvirtual Methods](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods).

Another alternative may be to introduce wrapper interfaces in your class under test, that can be mocked as usual: [Alternative to Mocking Concrete Classes](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#alternative-to-mocking-concrete-classes).

If you can't change any of the code it's not possible IMHO.

**UPDATE**:
As long `class B` is instantiated inside `A::fun1()`, it will be hard to mock `B` anyway. It should be passed as parameter, thus you have a chance to control the instantiation in your test method.

May be a viable solution for you could be to spoof the build environment for testing, and provide a declaration and definition for `class B` that provides a mock.

Comment: Hi g-makulik, how do I "spoof the build environment by providing a declaration and definition for class B that provides a mock"? Sorry, I am not able to understand how to do this.

Comment: The idea is to set different include/library pathes that your variant of `B.h` is seen before the 'real' one when compiling all the stuff in a test environment. But if this is possible at all depends on your build system's structure. If you can write your tests only against a precompiled library that contains `A`,`B` and `C` alltogether, this won't be possible at all.